# To rob the grave of the victims

Tags: expressions

In Napoleon Hill's "Think and grow rich" there is a sentence, which I do no understand

> I believe in the power of desire backed by faith, because I have seen
>   this power lift men from lowly beginnings to places of power and
>   wealth; I have seen it rob the grave of its victims [...]

What does *rob the grave of its victims* mean in this context (how can the power of desire rob someone's grave) ?

Comment: It means that the "power of desire backed by faith," etc., has prevented some people from dying prematurely—presumably because they are having such a great time being powerful and wealthy that they decide to keep living. In this description, "the grave" is a metaphor for death, and "its victims" are the people who would be dead and buried if not for the intervention of whatever Napoleon Hill is selling. But it would be cooler if it meant that the power of desire produces zombies.

Comment: Anyway, "robbing the grave of its victims" = "cheating Death of those who otherwise would have died." Claro?

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I understand. Without the power of desire, person X would die and fill the grave (with his or her corpse). With the power of desire, that same person continues to live such that his or her grave is empty/nonexistent. Hence, the power of desire prevented the body of the person to go into the grave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full paragraph from which you quoted reads:

> I believe in the power of desire backed by faith, because I have seen this power lift men from lowly beginnings to places of power and wealth; I have seen it rob the grave of its victims; I have seen it serve as the medium by which men staged a comeback after having been defeated in a hundred different ways; I have seen it provide my own son with a normal, happy, successful life, despite Nature’s having sent him into the world without ears.

The overall theme here seems to be that Hill's nostrums are a vehicle for succeeding against adversity, whether that adversity takes the form of the minor inconvenience represented by mortality, or — worse still — the tragedy of having been born earless.

Comment: +!. Although not everyone can be born with beautiful fox ears.

Comment: @SvenYargs - It is because I am so sentimentally attached to my beautiful ears — and thanks for your generous compliment, by the way — that I am especially sensitive to the plight of those unfortunate creatures who are born without them, even when they are only man-children.

Comment: @ErikKowal Thanks. But I still don't understand the part with robbing the graves.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Sentimentally and otherwise, I imagine.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko - I think Sven's comment pretty much nailed what Napoleon Hill was implying: the desire for the accumulation of wealth that Hill is trying to stoke in his readers (and, presumably, their ultimate achievement of the promised riches) is sufficiently motivating to the otherwise moribund that they decide not to croak after all, and rebound into renewed vitality, thereby somewhat postponing any prospective transformation into zombies.

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange passage because "to rob a grave" usually means to despoil an existing grave, i.e. in search of "grave goods" -- jewelry, gold, etc. Here it is supposed to mean to "cheat death". In any case, "death" (via the metonym "grave") could be a metaphor for despair, a spiritual death.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the entity being robbed is the grave, and the thing that is being stolen from it is its victims: those who would die and be buried in it, because in faith they do not truly die.

It does not mean that the victims are people having their graves robbed of valuables.

It has a parallel structure to "rob a woman of her jewelry".

It does not have a parallel structure to "rob the vault of a bank".